# Ubuntu Apache2 main DocumentRoot doesn't change

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, virtualhost

I've made a test machine with a basic MediaWiki install. Now I want to go to the Wiki with just the IP address and not having to type IP/MediaWiki. If I go to the IP address it shows me the Apache2 test page, but when I change the `DocumentRoot` I get `404 Not Found`, which is rubbish because I'm looking at the directory and files as we speak. I've set the permissions to `755` and the owner of the `var/www/html` folder to `www-data` and I've changed the `DocumentRoot` in:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

The content of both files are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mediawikia
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I check the `Main DocumentRoot` with `apachectl -S`, it always remains on `/var/www/html` and also giving me that `404 Not Found` error.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You mentioned running `apachectl -S`, can you update your question with its output? It may be helpful to also add the output of `a2query -s`. You mentioned modifying  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, what have you changed there (please update your post)? What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a default install, `000-default.conf` should be the only one you need to change (that's also assuming you don't need HTTPS for this).

You can double-check the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to confirm it contains only a symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Finally, after changing config files, you need to restart (or sometimes just reload) Apache so the changes take effect. Eg:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```